# Grub not showing windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have already viewed a dozens of answers. I have a different problem here. I had windows 10 installed. I recently dual booted my lenovo ideapad 310 with ubuntu 16.04. But since then my grub menu is not showing windows 10. Before installing ubuntu i tried to enter my BIOS but could not do that. Lenovo community forums suggested that i restart (not shutdown) my windows and then open BIOS when it restarts. And it worked and i changed boot order and installed ubuntu.

Now here are some points i want to mention

- Both operating systems are installed under Legacy support mode.
- I am able to view and mount windows partition in ubuntu.
- I have already used boot-repair but no luck.

Here are some outputs from some commands

`sudo update-grub`

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-77-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-77-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
Found FreeDOS on /dev/sda1
done
```

`sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd9fa2484

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    2050047    2048000  1000M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2          2052094  929521663  927469570 442.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda3        929521664 1951702742 1022181079 487.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1951703040 1953519615    1816576   887M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda5          2052096   75505220   73453125    35G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6         75507712  179953663  104445952  49.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7        179955712  188342271    8386560     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8        188344320  929521663  741177344 353.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

`/dev/sda5` is my root for ubuntu

`/dev/sda6` is my home for ubuntu

`/dev/sda8` is extra space

`/dev/sda1` is FreeDos i guess, i am not sure.

Here is my boot info summary generated by `boot-repair`

[boot info summary](https://pastebin.com/0Z6a5sXa)

Comment: What happens if you try to boot the FreeDos? Is that show in in grub? Doesn't that boot WIndows?

Comment: You are a life saver. How could not i try that before. Freedos is actually booting my windows. Can you please explain the  reason behind this and i will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like grub is identifying the Windows boot loader which is on `/dev/sda1` as FreeDOS. Your actual Windows install is on `/dev/sda3`, and on `/dev/sda1` you will have nothing but Windows' own boot loader. Why that would be detected as FreeDOS, I don't know, but that's what is apparently happening.

So, just boot into FreeDOS and you should boot into Windows. If you want to change the name, edit `/boot/grub/grub/cfg`, find a line that starts with `menuentry` and mentions FreeDOS, and change that line to read Windows. It should look something like this (not exactly like this, this is just an example the details will be different; only change the text inside the quotes):

```
menuentry "Windows 7 BIOS MBR" {
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod chain
     drivemap hd0 hd1
     chainloader (hd1,msdos2)+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes actually dev/sda1 is the previous windows that youve installed but the system recognised as Free dos. so in Ubuntu just type sudo os-prober whre you can confirm it. After that just type sudo update-grub and restart the pc. and load it from free dos.